# Configure TTL on Semaphores in Redis using Redisson

Tags: java, redis, semaphore, spring-webflux, redisson

I am trying to acquire a distributed lock using Redisson. I have narrowed it down to an `RSemaphore` since the critical section is sitting in a Reactive stream and Java's contract of a single thread owning and releasing a lock doesn't work here. The situation I am running into is that the lock Objects in Redis have a TTL of -1 (never expire). This semaphore is for locking around objects so our service cluster remains coordinated and will be creating thousands of semaphores with no reentrant requirement.

I cannot for the life of me find a way to set a TTL on the Semaphore Object. I see options for permit expiry but not for the semaphore itself. Zookeeper is not an option in this environment, but I know ZK has multiple options for solving this problem (`ChildReapers` and `CreateMode.CONTAINER`). This seems like an extremely basic requirement of the `RSemaphore` API.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded my Redisson library version to be able to access the `expire()` method. Apparently versions starting at 3.11.0 (?) have thos method inherited from `RExpirable`.